# Change the color for different elements in Oxygen XML Editor

Tags: xslt, appearance, oxygenxml, xml-editor

I am trying to change the blue, orange and "brown" color seen in the attached picture. I have search the preferences and manage to change other options in my editor but somehow can't seem  to find where to change this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct information here from the oxygen website

**TLDR:** *Options* > *Preferences* > *Editor* > *Syntax Highligt* > *(Elements/Attriubutes)*

https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/25.1/ug-editor/topics/preferences-colors-sh.html